# Conversion of sum of series into product form: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)} = \frac12 \prod_{n=2}^\infty \left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2-1} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, infinite-product

Show that the following series and product are equivalent:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} \right] = \dfrac{1}{2}  \prod_{n=2}^\infty \left[ 1+\dfrac{1}{n^2-1} \right]
$$

Thought of solving this through induction as the relation is true for 1....but don't know how to proceed with the n part...Please help!!

Answer (score 5):

$\frac 1{n(n+1)}= \frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$ so this is a [telescoping sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), almost all terms will cancel out:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n(n+1)}= 1 - \frac12 + \frac12 - \frac13 + \dots + \frac1{N-1}-\frac1N + \frac1N-\frac1{N+1}=1-\frac1{N+1}.$$

Similarly, you can see that in the product of the terms of the form $\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n-1)}$ a lot of terms cancel out, you only need to check which of them.

$$\prod_{n=2}^N \frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n-1)} = \frac{2^2}{3\cdot 1} \cdot \frac{3^2}{2\cdot 4} \dots \frac{(N-1)^2}{(N-2)N} \cdot \frac{N^2}{(N+1)(N-1)}=
2 \cdot \frac{N}{N+1}.$$

Now it only remains to look what happens for $N\to\infty$ or to notice that already partial sums are the same as partial products, as pointed out in [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456168/conversion-of-sum-of-series-into-product-form/456228?noredirect=1#comment981732_456228).

Comment: Since $1 - \frac{1}{N+1} = \frac{N}{N+1}$, you already showed the equality in the partial sum/product level!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I somehow ignored the partial sums, maybe because the question was about infinite sum/product.

Comment: thanks! ya partial sums and products are same but how to take limit infinity for product form?

Comment: @SheetalSarin [Infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) is simply defined as the limit of partial products. (In case it is zero, the infinite product is said to diverge.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** First, simplify the fractions to get

$$\prod\limits_{n = 2}^\infty 1 + \frac{1}{n^2 - 1} = \prod\limits_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}$$

Denote the partial product by $P_n$, and take a logarithm:

$$\log{P_N} = \log{\prod\limits_{n = 2}^N \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}} = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N \log{\frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}}$$

$$ = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N \log{n^2} - \log{(n^2 - 1)} = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N 2\log(n) - \log(n - 1) - \log(n + 1)$$

Now a lot of terms will telescope.

Comment: Of course, they would still telescope in the product, without taking the logarithms.